# How will I make a button disable when an input element is empty using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that my jquery code is not working thought if I simulate it, for me it is correct cause I used the same procedure, The output is this, I have two inputs, the other input works well if it is empty, the button is automatically disabled, however when I added an input element it did not work and did not disabled the button.Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is my code HTML

```
<div><label> Control Number: </label>
 <input name="get_control_num" style="text-transform:uppercase"
  class="form-control" id="sel_control_num" readonly required>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label> Quantity: <font color="red"> *Limit is up to 15 only!
  </font></label></label>
    <input class="form-control has-error has-danger" name="quantity"
       type="number" id="get_Elem" data-error="Need to input and add quantity before proceeding"
       onchange="addInputs(this)" required>
       <span class="pull-right help-block with-errors" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px;">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li></li>
        </ul>
       </span>
       <br>
    <input type="button" id="sb_add_ctrl" name="is_Sub" class="btn btn-primary"
     value="Add Control Number">
</div>
```

My JQuery code

// This is working for my input labeled "Quantity"

```
$(':input[id="sb_add_ctrl"]').prop('disabled', true);

$('input[id=get_Elem]').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(':input[type="button"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

//This is not working for my input labeled "Control Number"

```
$(':input[id="sb_add_ctrl"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $('input[id=sel_control_num]').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(':input[type="button"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your second bit of JQuery is looking for an input with an `id` attribute equal to `button`. You do not have a matching element in the HTML you posted. Did you mean to select `:input[type="button"]` or `:input[id="sb_add_ctrl"]`?

Comment: Hey sorry for the type error I forgot to change the id to type, @DakotaMethvin editted it, yes I've tried that  :input[id="sb_add_ctrl"] still not working, I dunno why

Comment: `#sel_control_num` seems to be a `readonly` input... And you expect a `keyup` event from it. Remove the `readonly` attribute. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette still the same :(

Comment: Hi , is there any other elements with id sel_control_num ?

Comment: Hi @Swati :) , just checked it. No just one.

Comment: @Swati Also I've tried to get rid of the attribute readonly, still it didn't worked

Comment: Also , both inputs need to filled then only button will enabled ?

Comment: Yes yes, that is correct @Swati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing two different events for same task you can merge them and then check both input values using `&&` so if both return true then only button will be enable else it will remain disable .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('[name="is_Sub"]').prop('disabled', true);

$('input[name=quantity] , input[name=get_control_num]').on('keyup change', function() {
  //check if both inputs has some value
  if (($("input[name=quantity]").val().trim() != '') && ($("input[name=get_control_num]").val().trim() != '')) {
    $('[name="is_Sub"]').prop('disabled', false); //then only enable
  } else {
    $('[name="is_Sub"]').prop('disabled', true); //disabled.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label> Control Number: </label>
  <input name="get_control_num" style="text-transform:uppercase" class="form-control" id="sel_control_num" required>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label> Quantity: <font color="red"> *Limit is up to 15 only!
  </font></label>
  <input class="form-control has-error has-danger" name="quantity" type="number" id="get_Elem" data-error="Need to input and add quantity before proceeding" required>
  <span class="pull-right help-block with-errors" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 11px;">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li></li>
        </ul>
       </span>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="sb_add_ctrl" name="is_Sub" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Control Number">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it is now working :) , but what if my control number has an attribute of readonly?

Comment: I copy pasted your code, when I tried to input quantity first and then control number, the button did not enable, but when I tried to to input control number and then quantity it worked. Haha I got confused. Sorry

Comment: I am not seeing that behaviour in above code snippet .. Did you run code snippet ? is there any such behaviour ?

Comment: Yes I run your code snippet it's working but when I copy to my file it created a bug :(

Comment: are `name` which i am using matches your html structure ? Also, put console inside `if..` see when it gets called .

Comment: Yes it is correct for the "name" attributes, it returned false to me when I console.log and then first input in quantity and then control number

Comment: can you show updated code in jsfiddle ? Also , don't accept answers until problem is solved :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228720/discussion-between-any-something-and-swati).